# Pharmacy graduate: What are my chances of obtaining a scholarship for physics graduate studies?

Tags: funding

**Background:** I am a pharmacy graduate who spent several years in business, but I always had strong passion to physics and now I want to change my career to theoretical physics. I have done many studies on my own and took recently a good collection of non-degree intermediate and advanced physics undergraduate courses. I have also shown excellent performance in those courses.

**Questions:** Would any respectful university (let's say in the top 100) be willing to adopt a case like me and offer me a scholarship for a master degree in physics or would they all necessitate full undergraduate certification in Physics in order to be eligible for scholarship? Some professors advised I should apply for a master degree, while some others (given my old age of 42 years) recommended that I should go straight into a specialized PhD in theoretical physics. What route should I prefer?

Comment: "Shopping" questions, which seek recommendations or lists of individual universities, academic programs, publishers, journals, research topics or similar as an answer or seek an assessment or comparison of such, are off-topic here.

Comment: @Atheist I'm not sure OP is looking for a specific recommendation rather than advice about whether it is realistic in their situation to apply generally; but OP should perhaps clarify as much.

Comment: Maybe I should remove the part about "please provide names" but still really I am confused about options whether I am pursuing the right track by chasing universities for graduate scholarships or is this a waste of time

Comment: @henning `Please provide names of universities if any.` sounds like seeking a recommendation

Comment: @Atheist True! I removed that part.

Comment: @henning I also removed it but not sure who removed first

Comment: @Omega Yes, we stood on each others feet for a second. :)

Comment: @henning, never mind :)

Comment: I think the first question you need to ask is whether or not you'll be accepted to a graduate program in Physics, Masters or Doctoral. There are loads of people who have stellar undergraduate and even industry experience in Physics who may beat you for a spot.

Comment: Let me pose another very important question: even if you can get a PhD do you have any chance for a reasonable job at academia.. Liberal sciences may be more forgiving, but being a 45-50 yo candidate for a tenure track job in physical sciences can be a challenge.

Comment: Yes you're wasting your time [seeking a scholarship, not studying physics].

Comment: It's not a scholarship you're aiming for, it's a teaching assistantship.  Your chances for that might be better if you apply for a PhD rather than a master's.  Make sure you have all the coursework needed, and look at similar questions on this site.